# Finding TeX Fonts for use in Python

Tags: fonts

I am using texlive on Windows Subsystem for Linux. I'm testing the quality of figures I can create using the python package `matplotlib`. One thing I'd like to be able to do is make the text in the figures match that of my documents/reports.

I am using `TeX Gyre Pagella` and `TeX Gyre Pagella Math` in my main document. I think, in order to tell matplotlib where to look for the font, I need to know where the files that define the font are.

I think the `TeX` fonts are packaged with my distribution (I don't ever remember installing them but they seem to just work when I compile my documents using LuaLatex), but I've not been able to dig them up.

Does anyone know where they are located?

Comment: Does `kpsewhich t1qpl.fd` or `kpsewhich texgyrepagella-regular.otf` work for you? If not,do a file search in Explorer.

Comment: Also, in case anyone is interested, I found how to specify it for `matplotlib` from the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668219/how-to-set-up-a-custom-font-with-custom-path-to-matplotlib-global-font). Make sure to use the actual font name and not the file name when specifying the `font.family` (e.g. for I would do `TeX Gyre Pagella` and _not_ `texgyrepagella-regular`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command to find files in your TeX distribution is `kpsewhich`.  In this case you would want to run either `kpsewhich t1qpl.fd` or `kpsewhich texgyrepagella-regular.otf`.

If `kpsewhich` doesn’t work, you can try a file search in Explorer.

An alternative to find the full path of a font file that might be in either the TeX distribution or a system directory is `luaotfload-tool` or `fc-list | grep`.  A way to find the filename of a font from its display name is `fc-match` or `luaotfload-tool --find`.

Comment: Thank you! `kpsewhich texgyrepagella-regular.otf` worked!